# Why are the two columns of content colliding, even if they are block elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a really simple responsive layout and althought it looks like it's working at the moment, when the screen shrinks the columns, despite being block elements, collide and I cannot figure out why, does anyone see an error?

my HTML:

```css
    *{

     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;

    }
    html{

     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;

    }
    body{

     height: 100%;
     width:100%;

    }
    .title{

     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 3em;
     margin: 2% 0% 2% 1%;

    }
    .col-1{

     width: 55%;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;

    }
    .col-2{

     width: 45%;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;

    }
    .columnTitle{

     font-size: 1.9em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     margin: 4% 0% 4% 4%;;

    }
    .paragraph{

     font-size: 1.5em;
     margin: 2%;
     text-align: justify;
     line-height: 1.3em;

    }
    /*/////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       media queries     //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){

     .col-1{

      display: block;
      width: 100%;


     }
     .col-2{

      display: block;
      width: 100%;
  
     }

    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    </head>
    <body>

     <header>

      <h1 class="title">This is a Title</h1>

     </header>


     <section class="col-1">

      <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the First Column</h1>
      <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

     </section>
     <section class="col-2">

      <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the Second Column</h1>
      <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

     </section> 

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I just found out that this problem is caused by the initial styling of the two columns, in particular by the "height:100%" style, can someone explain me why that was the problem?

Comment: I copied your code to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t19xut04/), can't find anything wrong. What exactly do you mean? Can you make a fiddle yourself? Or show us screenshots?

Comment: yeah the sfiddle looks right but I had to remove the style height:100%, from the initial col-1 and col-2 classes in order to make it work in chrome, otherwise the second column of content would get over the first one whenever the window is shrunk vertically.

Comment: @AlexTaietti You may want to consider the answer below, lol. It might fix your problem. Technically on your problem it does not even affect the height of 100% something.

Comment: I'll try your code just to see what was your solution althought now I fixed it, thanks by the way :) ; clear is not needed, because when a float element becomes a block element, due to the media querie, it will automatically break the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

First add auto-clear on your css.

```
.auto-clear:before, .auto-clear:after { content:" "; display:table; }
.auto-clear:after { clear:both; }
```

Then add a main container for your float columns. What this does is it clears your float elements. Not good at explanation, just try it, lmao.

--

Edit:

The problem on your html structure is because you did not clear your float elements.

--

```
    <div class="auto-clear">

        <section class="col-1">

            <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the First Column</h1>
            <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

        </section>
        <section class="col-2">

            <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the Second Column</h1>
            <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

        </section>  
    </div>
```

Solution 2:

Add a class on your css file.

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

Then put the 2 floated elements in a container. On the bottom of the last floated element, add an empty div that has a class of clear. What it does is the same, it clears your floated element. But in a messy way. You're creating unnecessary div. So best way is the First Solution I gave to you. (For me at least)

```
<div>
    <section class="col-1">

        <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the First Column</h1>
        <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

    </section>
    <section class="col-2">

        <h1 class="columnTitle">This is the Second Column</h1>
        <p class="paragraph">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </section>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```